# Extract data from the dom into my model

Tags: backbone.js

I have a searchfield that when used shows multiple results (search for Star Wars and you get about 6 results in a list form). Every result has a "add movie" button which when clicked should save the data of that movie into my rails model.

I want to use Backbone to get a dynamic view for this process, so that when the movie is added it shows instantly without refreshing. The easiest way to do this would be to extract the data from the HTML (title, image-url) from the selected movie and store it into my model.

I've checked the Backbone model documentation, and I've already did the codeschool Backbone.js course, but still I find it hard to get started. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: look up the template & render for backbone. Create an "addMovie" model, the acted on elem. The model will have a render method - that builds it. Create the template snippet that gets appended.

Comment: Can I use jQuery to grab the data from a element and then get Backbone to store it into my model?